How can I apply different functions to grouped columns in R?
What did you try and what were you expecting?
I tried using the dplyr package in R to group my data by the group column and apply different summary functions to two columns (value1 and value2). My code looked like this:
library(dplyr)
result <- df %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  summarize(
    value1_mean = mean(value1),
    value2_sum = sum(value2)
  )

I expected the output to look like this:
  group value1_mean value2_sum
  A     15          20
  B     35          60


The code looks correct. If you print the result object, what do you see?
